# Altium Designer Junction and Wiring Settings

Tags: schematics, altium

In Altium Designer I want to connect multiple wires in one junction but program doesn't allow me to do that and when I move to any components, wires get triangular shape. I want to just 90 degree movement of wires. I looked the schematic preferences and couldn't find correct settings.

Which setting parameter is for this purpose?

[image: Here is a example what i mean]

Comment: *I want to connect multiple wires in one junction* <--Connecting multiple wires (more than 3) to one junction is bad practice.

Comment: Drag mode is set with SPACE (while dragging).

Comment: To avoid the angled wires you circled above the Ground connection, move the Ground symbol left or right to avoid the four-way junction.  You should avoid four-way junctions as they can easily be misunderstood to be wires crossing without connection.

Comment: Regarding the _90 degree wire_ , as much as I remember you can press **space** while holding the wire to change the angle of wiring

Comment: Shift-spacebar will toggle 90, 45, any angle modes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altium converts your junctions for a reason. Cross junctions are difficult to interpret, especially when printed and possibly photocopied.

You can manually place your connections to avoid cross junctions, for example  by moving your ground connection:

[image]

You can change "Convert Cross-Junctions" setting in the schematic preferences.

[image]